# AsyncTask in LibGDX - example

Tags: java, asynchronous, libgdx

Did anyone used AsyncTask with AsyncResult and AsyncExecutor in LibGDX?
I want to run some audio recording and processing asynchronously with checking if result is ready.
This is part of my code:

```
private FftAnalysis analysis;
private AsyncExecutor executor;
private AsyncResult<Double> asyncResult;
(...)
public GameWorld(int midPointY) {
  executor = new AsyncExecutor(300); // I know how big this value is.
  analysis = new FftAnalysis();
  asyncResult = executor.submit(analysis);
}
public void update(float delta){
if(asyncResult.isDone()){ 
   freq = asyncResult.get();
   asyncResult = executor.submit(analysis);
}
```

The isDone() is never true and I don't see function call() from FftAnalysis ever executed...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `update` ever called? Is `GameWorld` a `Screen` that is set for the object that extends `Game`?

Comment: Have you tried with a sensible size for the thread pool? Having 300 threads sitting there all the tune seems wasteful at the very least. That said, I'd ask the same - are you sure you actually using this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just using the libgdx api to do that? Have a look at the Timer class and Task class here: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html .

Basically you can run your code in a separate thread and get the result when it is finished.

Comment: actually, as per http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncTask.html and http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncExecutor.html, these **are** part of the LibGDX API.

Comment: I see, anyway it doesn't seems so widely used. For an example of that you can look at [AssetLoadingTask](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/26f1c3fbc5a96ffd9e63d31c2b07f8d5dac9c95d/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/assets/AssetLoadingTask.java). Anyway my advice is to re-think of your solution in terms of [Timer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.html) and Timer.task . Hope this can help you.